# Matching the first <p> that does not start with an image in regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In PHP, I'm trying to match the first paragraph tag that is not immediately followed by an `<img>` tag, and add a class to that paragraph tag.

For example, it would add a class to:

```
<p>Text</p>
```

and

```
<p><strong>Strong text</strong></p>
```

but not:

```
<p><img src="" /></p>
```

Here's what I have so far which successfully adds a class to the first paragraph tag, but it doesn't skip until it finds a paragraph tag that doesn't immediately contain an image:

```
preg_replace('/<p>/','<p class="first">', $text, 1);
```

Thoughts? Apologies if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/<p>(?!<img)/<p class="first">/
```